# Ajax call not working in Virtual Host in WAMP

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, virtualhost

I am working on a CI project, and for that, I have created a virtual host in wamp. It's working good. But the main problem started now. Whenever I call Ajax request it with/without giving the ajax post URL it shows a result. I don't know what is the issue..

I am clicking on forgot password link and then it opens a popup with forgot password form.

**Without URL**

```
$.get('').done(function (msg) {
                console.log('Yes');
                console.log(msg);
            }).fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log(status);
                console.log(error);
            });
```

**Result**
[image]

In this case I am getting the result (it's going in "done") but giving me the whole login page HTML.

**With URL**

```
$.get('http://fileupload.local/login/getresetpassword').done(function (msg) {
                console.log('Yes');
                console.log(msg);
            }).fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log(status);
                console.log(error);
            });
```

**Result**
[image]

I have tried too many solutions over google, but couldn't find the right one. Now I am pulling my hair and want to complete it.

Comment: The issue seems to be related to the server side, not the client one. You should add your controller's code. There must be a way to tell CI to send JSON (like you seem to expect) instead of HTML.

Comment: @MaxouMask I have tried everything.. There is a HTML printed inside the function getresetpassword, so therefor there is no server issue. The question is why it is going into .done even if I haven't provide any URL. I have also tried printing echo "Test" inside the function.

Comment: if u not giving the url inside $.get() it may taking the current url of your page and sent ajax request.

Comment: @VibinTV :  and if I giving full url then?

Comment: is it working by giving full url?

Comment: @VibinTV - No it's giving me the same result.

Comment: What is your actual problem? Did u get the forgot password page by giving the current url? also try what you get when goto that link by pasting it in the address bar  of browser

Comment: The forgot password form is resided in the getresetpassword, and I am trying to call the function using ajax....

Comment: have you not get the desired html output from the ajax call?

Comment: @VibinTV - nope that is the problem, that's why I am frustrated

Comment: then it will be your server side issue. it is output something thats why the .done function is working. U need to check your server side code rather than client side

Comment: @AlpeshTrivedi, please show your server-side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a config issue. It resolved by just change `$config['uri_protocol']  = 'QUERY_STRING';` to `$config['uri_protocol']  = 'REQUEST_URI';`

Answer (score 0):

Your Ajax looks ok to me. It should work. I have some suggestions:

- Open directly Url: `http://fileupload.local/login/getresetpassword` in your browser. We will see the result (Seem that it will return the whole page?)
- Check the server code. I think it's our main issue. Will it return the JSON type or not?